# Joining large dataset with other comparatively smaller datasets with spark sql

Tags: join, apache-spark-sql

I have a case where i have one large dataset (ds), which has 1 million records or more, I have 3 relatively smaller datasets (ds1,ds2,ds3), which have maximum 10K records.

Each smaller dataset (ds1,ds2,ds3) has joining key as myKey.
I have to join ds with ds1 and return ds1.IMP_TYPE (on ds.key=ds.myKey)
after that if ds still has null values join with ds2 for those null values,and if still has null values join it with ds3.

I am using spark SQL to perform the 3 different joins.

in first join I am joining ds with ds1:

```
spark.sql("select ds.*,ds1.IMP_TYPE as IT1 from ds left join ds1 on ds.key=ds2.myKey").createOrReplaceTempView("temp")
```

in second join I am joining ds with ds2:

```
spark.sql("select ds.*,ds2.IMP_TYPE as IT2 from ds left join ds2 on ds.key=ds2.myKey and isnull(ds.IT1) '').createOrReplaceTempView("temp")
```

in the third join I am joining ds with ds3:

```
spark.sql("select ds.*,ds3.IMP_TYPE as IT3 from ds left join ds1 on ds.key=ds3.myKey and isnull(ds.IT1) and isnull(ds.IT2)").createOrReplaceTempView("temp")


String finalSql="select *,concat(case when isnull(IT1) then ‘’ else IT1 end ,
            case when isnull(IT2) then ‘’ else IT2 end, 
            case when isnull(IT3) then ‘’ else IT3 end
) as FINAL_KEY from ds";
spark.sql(dinalSql).drop(col("IT1")).drop(col("IT2")).drop(col("IT3")).createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")
```

This is how I am getting my final desired table. Is there any better way to perform this activity? I am aware it's going to be used in cluster mode.

Comment: Java has nothing to do with it.

Comment: then what is better way to do this in spark,that my question

Comment: Indeed that is the question.

Comment: Have you tied an .explain?

Comment: tried I mean of course